# Office 365 SharePoint online, public facing MasterPage not updating for anonymous user

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, office365

We have a MasterPage for public facing site on Office 365 SharePoint Online
Any updation to masterpage was working fine till 3 days earlier, but update is not working now for anonymous user but logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you checked-in, published and approved it?